# Golang gorm URL escaped

Tags: go, range

I have problem with displaying URL from database in my template. I have struct:

```golang
type Tag struct {
    gorm.Model
    URL:       string
    userID:    uint
}
```

when I fetch all tags and try display it

```
{{range $element := .}}
{{$element.URL}}
{{end}}
```

I get escaped url. I see before was available | unescape but this don't exist anymore. I try also with custom function to return template.URL but still dont work.

This is my try:

```
"unscape" : func(s string) template.URL {
    return template.URL(fmt.Sprint(s))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to tell template engine that url is safe.

To achieve it need to return `template.HTML` or `template.URL`.

```
funcMap := template.FuncMap{
  "safeHTML" : template.HTML,
  "safeURL" : template.URL,
}
```

And then try to call Your method in template expression

```
{{range $element := .}}
{{safeURL $element.URL}}
{{end}}
```

By [manual for template package](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#hdr-Typed_Strings):

**Typed Strings**

> By default, this package assumes that all pipelines produce a plain text string. It adds escaping pipeline stages necessary to correctly and safely embed that plain text string in the appropriate context.
>
> When a data value is not plain text, you can make sure it is not over-escaped by marking it with its type.
>
> Types HTML, JS, URL, and others from content.go can carry safe content that is exempted from escaping.
>
> The template

```
Hello, {{.}}!
```

> can be invoked with

```
tmpl.Execute(out, template.HTML(`<b>World</b>`))
```

> to produce

```
Hello, <b>World</b>!
```

instead of the

```
Hello, &lt;b&gt;World&lt;b&gt;!
```

> that would have been produced if {{.}} was a regular string.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why but I must save it in variable to it be correct I fix it like this.

```
                "safe": func(s string) template.URL {
                   fixedurl := template.URL(s)
                   return  fixedurl
                },
```